# Hibernate not found entity for my query

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have an entity with four many-to-many associations:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "userInfo")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "getFullUser", query = "select u " +
                " from UserInfo u " +
                " join fetch u.userImage ui " +
                " join fetch u.logInfo " +
                " join fetch u.userQuestions " +
                " join fetch u.userPostsComments " +
                " join fetch u.userPosts  " +
                " join fetch u.answers  " +
                " where u.userId = :id")
})
public class UserInfo {

    public static final String GET_SMALL_USER = "getSmallUser";
    public static final String GET_COMMON_USER = "getCommonUser";
    public static final String GET_FULL_USER = "getFullUser";
    public static final String DELETE_USER = "deleteUser";
    public static final String FIND_USERS = "findUsers";
    public static final String GET_USERS_BY_BIRTHDATE = "getUsersByBirthDate";
    public static final String GET_USERS_EMAILS_BY_DATE = "getUsersEmailsByDate";
    public static final String CHECK_USER = "checkUser";

    private long userId;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private long rating;
    private Date createDate;
    private java.sql.Date birthDate;
    private List<Questions> userQuestions;
    private List<PostsComments> userPostsComments;
    private List<PostsInfo> userPosts;
    private List<Answer> answers;
    private UserImages userImage;
    private LogInfo logInfo;

    public UserInfo(){}

    public UserInfo(String email, String firstName, String lastName, java.sql.Date birthDate){
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }


    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "rating")
    public long getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "createDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderColumn
    public List<Questions> getUserQuestions() {
        return this.userQuestions;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderColumn
    public List<PostsComments> getUserPostsComments() {
        return this.userPostsComments;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderColumn
    public List<PostsInfo> getUserPosts() {
        return this.userPosts;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderColumn
    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return this.answers;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userInfo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    public UserImages getUserImage() {
        return userImage;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, mappedBy = "userInfo",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public LogInfo getLogInfo() {
        return logInfo;
    }

    @Column(name = "birthDate", nullable = false)
    public java.sql.Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

}
```

Code where i get full user:

```
   @Override
public UserInfo getFullUser(long id) {
    Query<UserInfo> query = session.createNamedQuery(UserInfo.GET_FULL_USER, UserInfo.class)
            .setParameter("id", id);


    UserInfo user = query.getSingleResult();

    return user;
}
```

When i try to get full user, hibernate create next sql query:

```
Hibernate: select userinfo0_.user_id as user_id1_17_0_,
    userimages1_.user_id as user_id1_16_1_,
    loginfo2_.user_id as user_id1_4_2_,
    userquesti3_.question_id as question1_13_3_,
    userpostsc4_.post_comment_id as post_com1_8_4_,
    userposts5_.post_id as post_id1_9_5_,
    answers6_.answer_id as answer_i1_0_6_,
    userinfo0_.birthDate as birthDat2_17_0_,
    userinfo0_.createDate as createDa3_17_0_,
    userinfo0_.email as email4_17_0_,
    userinfo0_.firstName as firstNam5_17_0_,
    userinfo0_.lastName as lastName6_17_0_,
    userinfo0_.rating as rating7_17_0_,
    userimages1_.image_l as image_l2_16_1_,
    userimages1_.image_m as image_m3_16_1_,
    userimages1_.image_s as image_s4_16_1_,
    loginfo2_.mail_h as mail_h2_4_2_,
    loginfo2_.pass_h as pass_h3_4_2_,
    userquesti3_.createDate as createDa2_13_3_,
    userquesti3_.title as title3_13_3_,
    userquesti3_.user_id as user_id4_13_3_,
    userquesti3_.user_id as user_id4_13_0__,
    userquesti3_.question_id as question1_13_0__,
    userquesti3_.userQuestions_ORDER as userQues5_0__,
    userpostsc4_.comment as comment2_8_4_,
    userpostsc4_.createDate as createDa3_8_4_,
    userpostsc4_.post_id as post_id4_8_4_,
    userpostsc4_.user_id as user_id5_8_4_,
    userpostsc4_.user_id as user_id5_8_1__,
    userpostsc4_.post_comment_id as post_com1_8_1__,
    userpostsc4_.userPostsComments_ORDER as userPost7_1__,
    userposts5_.createDate as createDa2_9_5_,
    userposts5_.title as title3_9_5_,
    userposts5_.user_id as user_id5_9_5_,
    userposts5_.views as views4_9_5_,
    userposts5_.user_id as user_id5_9_2__,
    userposts5_.post_id as post_id1_9_2__,
    userposts5_.userPosts_ORDER as userPost6_2__,
    answers6_.question_id as question3_0_6_,
    answers6_.text as text2_0_6_,
    answers6_.user_id as user_id4_0_6_,
    answers6_.user_id as user_id4_0_3__,
    answers6_.answer_id as answer_i1_0_3__,
    answers6_.answers_ORDER as answers_5_3__
  from userInfo userinfo0_
   inner join userImages userimages1_ on userinfo0_.user_id=userimages1_.user_id
   inner join logInfo loginfo2_ on userinfo0_.user_id=loginfo2_.user_id
   inner join Questions userquesti3_ on userinfo0_.user_id=userquesti3_.user_id
   inner join postsComments userpostsc4_ on userinfo0_.user_id=userpostsc4_.user_id
   inner join postsInfo userposts5_ on userinfo0_.user_id=userposts5_.user_id
   inner join Answer answers6_ on userinfo0_.user_id=answers6_.user_id
  where userinfo0_.user_id=?
```

and throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1555)
at ru.projects.prog_ja.dao.Hibernate.HibernateUserDAOImpl.getFullUser(HibernateUserDAOImpl.java:72)
at TestMain.run(TestMain.java:56)
at TestMain.main(TestMain.java:20)
```

Although I have this entity in the table, and when i delete the last 4 join fetches that attach collections all works fine.

I don't understand where is my error, help me please

Comment: Probably one of the joins returns null data so that your query is not return any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an inner join in your query. You will only get a result if every joined table have data. That means your query will only hit if your user has: userImage, logInfo, userQuestions …

The following expample show 3 tables. Only **user1** and **user2** have entries in all tables. But **user3** do not have an entry in LOGDATA-Table.

```
USERTABLE
userid  name        age
user1   Peter       20
user2   Hartmut     60
user3   Waltraud    85

LOGTABLE
userid  logtext
user1   uploaded data
user2   posted message

POSTABLE
userid  message subject
user1   Hello World javascript
user2   Hello Foo   java
user3   Old World   cobol
```

If you join all tables with an inner join:

```
SELECT * FROM USERDATA
INNER JOIN POSTDATA ON USERDATA.userid = POSTDATA.userid
INNER JOIN LOGDATA ON USERDATA.userid = LOGDATA.userid
```

You will get:

```
userid  name    age userid  message     subject     userid  logtext
user1   Peter   20  user1   Hello World javascript  user1   uploaded data
user2   Hartmut 60  user2   Hello Foo   java        user2   posted message
```

For your usecase you should use an **OUTER-JOIN**. For exmaple the query:

```
SELECT * FROM USERDATA
FULL OUTER JOIN POSTDATA ON USERDATA.userid = POSTDATA.userid
FULL OUTER JOIN LOGDATA ON USERDATA.userid = LOGDATA.userid
```

Will result in:

```
userid  name        age userid  message     subject     userid  logtext
user1   Peter       20  user1   Hello World javascript  user1   uploaded data
user2   Hartmut     60  user2   Hello Foo   java        user2   posted message
user3   Waltraud    85  user3   Old World   cobol       NULL    NULL
```